# Using a href link to pass parameters to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a `jsp` file where in I have a `String` variable s. Now I want to pass this to a `servlet` using `servlet`.
In the `href` tag i gave,

```
<a href="link?user= <%=s%> "> click me </a>
```

But it shows an error how else can I send this.

Please help me out..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work fine, but there are some minor mistakes here, which I'm not sure whether they are due to mis-typing here or there are actually in your code.

**First** have your link like this:

```
<a href="link?user=<%=s%> "> click me </a>
```

See? No spaces. And as your variable is `s`, why using `a`?
**Second** in your servlet use this to receive the parameter:

```
request.getParameter("s")
```

Comment: Its due to mistyping here. The variable name is a. And btw how do I send more than a parameter?

Comment: You can use `&` between each parameter. But remember, do not use `space`.

Comment: Ya ok Thanks. The space is the problem. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually have the spaces like that? Try this:
    "> click me